# Issue tracking with automatically generated issues

Tags: issue-tracking

In my company we are now looking to start using an issue tracker. So far we've been using our task management system for issue tracking, and now we need something more advanced.

We found out that we have lots (1000s) of small issues that we can automatically generate, and we want to handle them based on a prioritized queue. Such small issues are usually content issues. Sometimes issues are outright errors that come up, and we want to prioritize these based on how critical the error is and how many users encountered it.

Another feature we are looking for is the ability to aggregate issues that are identical, based on some identification string we can generate. We would also like it to be possible to aggregate issues manually - i.e. mark two issues as duplicates in an easy way via the UI.

Finally, we are interested in the issue tracker to have a usable set of tools for managing issues manually - prioritizing, setting owners, generating reports, etc.

My question to you is: what issue tracker would you recommend we use?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is still active, I am a developer @ [bontq.com](http://www.bontq.com). It is an issue tracking system with both web access and Win/Mac desktop apps, SVN, GIT integration, public API, prioritisation and a bunch of other useful features, which you have not mentioned in your question. You can create a free account there and try the system  - maybe it is the one you are looking for.

If you will have any questions regarding the system (especially web interface and API) - you can ask me here. I will gladly help you.

PS: this response is not an advertisement - just trying to be helpful.